# How to do proofs involving sets

Tags: proof-writing

I have just recently started preparing for a course I will be taking next year, but I have very limited knowledge as it relates to proofs. It seems as though the only proofs I am slightly familiar with are proofs by induction. I was wondering if there is a systematic way to approaching proofs and if there are any "rules," as silly as that may sound. As for my specific question, I stumbled upon this:

Let A be a set.

$\emptyset \in A \Rightarrow \exists B \hspace{2 mm} s.t. \hspace{2 mm} A =  \wp (B)$

Determine, with proof, if the above statement is true.

Comment: I'm having trouble reading what the problem is asking.  Could you rewrite or rephrase it?

Comment: Done. First time using this

Comment: I'm not sure what that symbol is supposed to be when you say A = ?(B).  Could you clarify?

Comment: It is the power set symbol. \wp

Comment: I don't know for sure, but this doesn't seem true. If $A = \{\emptyset, x, y\}$, then $A$ has 3 elements, but the power set of a finite set has a power of 2 elements.

Comment: You got it @HASSOUN !

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean @gorzardfu . Can you clarify?

Comment: You're right @HASSOUN , the statement above is not true for the exact same reason you just said.  A set being nonempty does not mean it is the power set of another set, and one reason is because, as you stated, power sets must have cardinality 2^n where n is a natural number including possibly 0.

Comment: Would that be considered a "proof"?